# Expected ')' before '*' token (C++(Qt))

Tags: c++, qt

firstly Excuseme for duplicate Question i cant solve my problem with that , I was going to compile this c++ class , compiler error was : "Expected ')' before '*' token" , i got error from cpp file line 3 constructor header first parameter ,  F1 plz

dropdownbutton.h

```
#ifndef DROPDOWNBUTTON_H
#define DROPDOWNBUTTON_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QToolBar>    
class DropdownButton : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:

public slots:

private :
    QToolButton * button   ;
    QMenu * buttonMenu  ;
public:
    explicit DropdownButton(QWidget *parent =0 , QToolBar * container =0 , QAction * actionsArray =0) ;

};

#endif // DROPDOWNBUTTON_H
```

dropdownbutton.cpp

```
#include "dropdownbutton.h"

    DropdownButton(QWidget * parent , QToolBar * container , QAction * actionsArray ) : QWidget(parent)// ERROR LINE
    {

        button = new QToolButton(parent);
        buttonMenu = new QMenu(button);
        while(actionsArray!='\0')
        {
            buttonMenu->addAction(actionsArray);
            actionsArray++ ;
        }
    button->setMenu(buttonMenu);
    button->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);

    container->addWidget(container);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is this:

`DropdownButton::DropdownButton(QWidget * parent, ...)`

The `DropdownButton::` indicates that this function isn't just any ordinary function, it's a member function of the class `DropdownButton`.